# Should abstract superclass contain protected non-abstract methods which are to be used by some and not all subclasses

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

I have an abstract class as below:

```
public class AbstractClass {
   
    private String getA() {
       return "A";
    }
    
    protected String getB() {
        return getA().concat("-B");
    }

}
```

Now, all subclasses will use the `getB()` method. That is why I have made it `protected`. But not all subclasses will use the `getA()` method. Only a subset will use it. So, should I still make it `protected` or keep it `private`?

Comment: Why would you make it private if not all of the subclasses will actually use it? That would mean that none of the subclasses can use it... If you want to _prevent_ some subclasses from calling a method, you should make a more complex class hierarchy (and maybe use `sealed`/`permits` to specify which classes can extend which specific class.

Comment: Do you mean that all subclasses will call `getA` indirectly, via `getB`, but that some will also call `getA` directly?

Comment: @tgdavies yes exactly. Basically, should a superclass contain methods whose implementation will be static but whether they will be used or not depends upon a subclass ?

I mean if we keep on adding protected non-abstract methods in superclass even if they are required by just one subclass, doesn't it become a util class instead?

Comment: In general, if you can make something private. Make it private. Why don't you think getA should be private. Do you expect subclasses to call it directly? Do you expect them to override it?

Comment: @matt getA() will not be overriden. It is just that it will not be used by all subclasses, just a subset. So, is it a good design pattern to add protected non-abstract methods which will not be overriden but will be used by subset of subclasses, maybe even just one subclass ?

Comment: If a subclass is going to use it by calling it directly, then you cannot have it private.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with design patterns. I have corrected the tagging accordingly. It's about OO fundamentals like inheritance and access modifiers. To answer your question, if you want to make a member available to subclasses it *must* be defined as protected or public.

Comment: Note, if you want to prevent subclasses to override members e.g. getA() you must define it as final: `protected final string getA()`

Comment: I feel that this question is seeking opinions about code design considerations, and is therefore not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you make `getA()` private, none of the subclasses will be able to access it.
You are therefore forced to make it protected (or public).

Comment: one other option is to implement getA() in all subclasses which want to use it. But that leads to code duplication. So, wanted to know should a superclass contain methods whose implementation will be static but whether they will be used or not depends upon a subclass ? 
I mean if we keep on adding protected non-abstract methods in superclass even if they are required by one subclass, doesn't it become a util class instead?

Comment: Why wouldn’t you just add it to the one subclass that needs it in that case?